# make a user input with text before wich works even if printing from another thread

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a python like user input in wich you can print to the screen from one thread,  while waiting for an input from another thread

for example when I do something like this:

```
std::cout << "Your input: "; std::cin>> Input;
```

and at the same time from another thread I do something like this:

```
std::cout<<"hello\n";
```

I get  something like this:

```
Your Input: hello
| //still waiting for input here
```

but I want to get something like this:

```
hello
Your Input: |
```

can you help me to do it

Comment: Please show an actual [mre] - we have no idea what you did and why it doesn't work

Comment: Unless you deliberately sequence stuff happening in different threads what you get out is at the whim of the gods.

Comment: I want to get the  text before the user input go to the bottom when printing  from something else while awaiting for user input

Comment: @user4581301 is right. You could even get the output jumbled together, like this: hellYour Input:o. Without some sort of synchronization mechanism between the two threads, there's no way to format the output to your liking.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Windows, then I recommend that you use one thread for managing all the input/output, using the functions [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) and [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition). That thread can wait for input events and output requests from the other thread by using the function [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects).

Comment: **I am voting to reopen the question because** in my opinion, the question is useful and also is answerable. It is not possible to solve this problem using standard C++, but it is possible using platform-specific functionality. Therefore, a good answer would provide examples on how to solve the problem on several common platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C++ cannot rearrange text already on the terminal. You'll need a helper library that knows how to do complex iteractions with the specific terminals of various operating systems, such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)